# Slick Grid how to add seek top & seek bottom scroll buttons?

Tags: grid, slickgrid

I'm using slick grid for my application, I need a seek top & seek bottom buttons, **Example:** if user clicks **seek bottom** user can directly go to bottom of the grid, vice-versa, I'm completely new to slick Grid,Thanks in advance.

```
Seek Top      Seek Bottom 
 |<<            >>|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, you can just grab the scroll bar 'visible' section and drag it to the bottom. Paging is something like what you want:
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

However in the end, you can do what you want using `grid.scrollRowIntoView()`.
'Seek Top' is scrolling to row 0, 'Seek Bottom' is scrolling to row (data.length - pagesize), or just (data.length - 1): the final row.